# Add Vue.js to existing non-single page application

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue-router

I have a CMS backed web site where Vue.js was added to handle a UI feature of the site. The feature has tabs that switch content on the page. I need to make the tabs deep linkable as in there needs to be a way to have a certain tab set as active on page load. I can easily achieve this using a URL has but I would like to see if I can just use the Vue.js router. I haven't been able to find any resources to add the router to an existing site that isn't fully powered by Vue.js.

Is there way to add vue-router without any additional server configuation?

Answer (score 2):

You could use Vue Router in the hash mode for history. Your URL would end up being something like `www.example.com/post/1#tab1` and `www.example.com/post/1#tab2`.

One caveat, if SEO is important to this site, then you would need to do the routing on the server to make the page easier to crawl by Google.